# After using combinations with replacement, how to remove tuples with combinations that I don't want

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm trying to get a list of lists (or tuples) which follows a pattern something like this:

```
[1,1,1,2]
[1,1,2,2]
[1,2,2,2]
[1,2,2,3]
[1,2,3,3]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Using itertools.combinations_with_replacement I've gotten close, but I end up with lists which jump values for example:

```
[1,1,1,3]
or
[2,2,2,3]
```

I don't want this. I always want to start at 1, and increase until the list is filled, and then increase to the next value.

If I'm using itertools, then is there a way to remove the lists that I don't want?

Comment: So you want all of them to start at 1 and never increase by more than 1?

Comment: Can you explain _exactly_ what the pattern is here? Why is it not starting at `[1, 1, 1, 1]`? Why do you go up to `[1, 2, 2, 2]` but not `[2, 2, 2, 2]`? What's wrong with `[2, 2, 2, 3]`? What comes after `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? Should there be a `[1, 1, 2, 3]`? What should the full output be?

Comment: @tzaman, it's actually for binning some data for machine learning. It's actually a counterpart question to  this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050937/how-to-create-my-own-hyper-parameter-within-sklearn

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes! And I've gotten two solutions now, so thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using combinations, I would generate the pattern directly.

Create a list of 1's with the desired length and iterate backward, changing the list accordingly.

```
def generate_increment(n):
    lst = [1] * n
    result = []
    for k in range(n-1):
        lst[-1] += 1
        result.append(lst[:])
        for i in range(len(lst)-2, k, -1):
            a, b = lst[i], lst[i+1]
            if a != b:
                lst[i] = b
                result.append(lst[:])
    return result

>>print(*generate_increment(4), sep='\n')

[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It feels like validating the results of `combinations` will be a bigger effort than simply creating those lists you need.

This can be done with a recursive function that adds with each step what value to add to the list until a defined size:

```py
def gen_list(pre, size):
    if size == 1:
        return [pre]

    res = gen_list(pre + [pre[-1]], size - 1)
    res.extend(gen_list(pre + [pre[-1]+1], size-1))
    return res

for l in gen_list([1], 4):
    print(l)
```

Which prints:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!